# Jaspersoft Table Element No data displayed

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table component on a subreport being used with an independent data source (dataset) thats hooked onto the table object. The table has two columns, the following issues arise upon debugging:

- Not all descriptions are loaded from the query I used
- The second column is not showing the data at all

Is there any properties that I am missing?

Thank you
Kind reagrds
Zain Nabi

[image]

Comment: If you skip Jaspersoft and connect directly to the dbms, will you get the correct result?

Comment: @jarlh that's indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Jasperstudio reports require all parameter names to be the same.